# Google Contacts API was turned off in our Developer Console mysteriously

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

Our application relies on the Google Contacts API.  Access to the Google Contacts API was disabled in our Application on August 7th, 2017 at 6pm (Pacific).  Graph:

[image]

We weren't notified by Google and I'm certain we haven't hit the quota.  Our users let us know and we were able to re-enable it this morning successfully.

But we're trying to figure out how this happened.  Has anyone else seen API access disabled without their knowledge... or can someone from Google help us track this down?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, had the same issue today with one of our projects that is using Google Contacts API - found Contacts API disabled...
And that came with another quite annoying issue when we started to get "unusual traffic" web page content with the CAPTCHA thing instead of error, when trying to access Google Contacts API.

The detailed issue was registered by me here, you can take a look:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64472602

Comment: Ok thanks for that info!  Glad we're not the only ones.  We aren't seeing any CAPTCHA issues however.  Strange.

Comment: @cortfr , you'd probably have to debug your application to find the CAPTCHA response. Previously, I've found it by querying the API via Postman; there you'll see the HTML response.